# Handle unhandled exception from Python package

Tags: python, django, wordpress

I have successfully incorporated my Wordpress blog into my Django app through [the-real-django-wordpress](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/the-real-django-wordpress) Python package ([Github](https://github.com/sunlightlabs/django-wordpress)).

The only things I needed to do were to:

- add the Wordpress database credentials to the Django settings,
- include the URLconf of the package into `urls.py`,
- [override the package templates](https://github.com/sunlightlabs/django-wordpress#default-templates) in order to display the posts the way I want.

---

If however the Wordpress database happens to be offline, I get a Python exception.

> OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.2.2'
>   (110)")

The Python code being part of the package, and thus not in my code, where should I then handle the exception in order to display an error message?

Comment: can you check connection before use it ? for example in view or models ?

Comment: That's the point, the view is not part of my code. All I did was basically to include the package and go to mydjangoapp.com/blog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have your `500.html` template simply display the error message you want?

Otherwise, you could create a middleware to catch this error:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

class CatchOperationalError(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if type(exception).__name__ == 'OperationalError':  # replace with proper isinstance
            return render(request, 'wordpress_down.html')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process_exception

Another option would be to wrap each individual view in a try/except.